# How to map matched records returned from a join instead of separate rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

**Scenario :**

I have two tables, structured as following.

Table 1 : **images**

```
+--------+------------+
| img_id |  img_name  |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | image1.jpg |
|      2 | image2.jpg |
|      3 | image3.jpg |
+--------+------------+
```

Table 2 : **image_tags**

```
+---------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
| cord_id | img_id | tag_text | xcord | ycord |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
| 1       | 1      | Tag1     | 28.1   | 30.4   |
| 2       | 1      | Test Tag | 23.4   | 4.5    |
+---------+--------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Now i want the images along with their tags which is quite simple using the left join

```
SELECT img_id, img_name,tag_text, xcord,ycord FROM images t1 LEFT JOIN image_tags t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

This query results in the following data set

```
+--------+------------+----------+--------+--------+
| img_id | img_name   | tag_text | xcord  | ycord  |
+--------+------------+----------+--------+--------+
| 1      | image1.jpg | Tag1     | 28.1   | 30.4   |
| 1      | image1.jpg | Test Tag | 23.4   | 4.5    |
| 2      | image2.jpg | NULL     | NULL   | NULL   |
| 3      | image3.jpg | NULL     | NULL   | NULL   |
+--------+------------+----------+--------+--------+
```

**Problem :**

Now using PHP (or MYSQL if possible), i want the results from the **image_tags** table to be concatenated with each row in form of an array.
So that when i loop through the records in Angular, i have images along with their **tags in form of an array** instead of two separate rows as you can see the first two rows in the result set.

Desired result example,

```
{
  cord_id : 1,
  img_id : 1,
  tags : [{
        tag_text : "Tag1",
        xcord : 28.1,
        ycord : 30.4,
     },{
        tag_text : "Test Tag",
        xcord : 23.4,
        ycord : 4.5,
     }
  ]
}
```

I have studied about **map()** function in PHP but unable to achieve this.

> **Note:** I am using Codeigniter, so if that has some relevant support to achieve this, that would also work for me.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try with [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) ?

Comment: Yes i did, but could not achieve that mentioned desired result

Comment: @YousalfHassan: How about the expectation of columns xcord, ycord? Can you please write down your expectation into one table like you did with others? By PHP, it's easy to create the JSON as your desired result from your query result.

Comment: @TuanDuong Thanks for taking interest , i have resolved the issue using two different functions for fetching images and then fetching their tags when loops through them. +1

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with just one query.

Since you have a unique ID you can use it as an index for your array.

```
$images = array();
foreach($queryResults as $result){
  if(!isset($images[$result['img_id']])){
    $images[$result['img_id']] = array();
    $images[$result['img_id']]['cord_id'] = $result['cord_id'];
    $images[$result['img_id']]['img_id']  = $result['img_id'];
    $images[$result['img_id']]['tags']    = array();
  }
  $tag = array(
          'tag_text'=>$result['tag_text'],
          'xcord'=> $result['xcord'],
          'ycord'=> $result['ycord']
        );
  $images[$result['img_id']]['tags'][] = $tag;
}
```